# No item images in RSS feed in almost no reader

Tags: image, rss, feed, feedly

Im trying to display item images within my (valid) RSS feed. But almost no reader (browser ex. "feedly" nor several IOS apps) is displaying them. I already use the "DATA"-term to show them up but it doesn't help. Is the syntax wrong? Are the images just too big (50>500k)?

The feed is located at: http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/rssfeed.xml

Code (excerpt):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<title>Videospielgeschichten.de - Geschichte spielend erzählt</title>
<atom:link href="http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/rssfeed.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
<link>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de</link>
<description>Wir veröffentlichen Artikel und Geschichten über klassische Video- und Computerspiele.</description>
<language>de-de</language>
<image>
<title>Videospielgeschichten.de - Geschichte spielend erzählt</title>
<url>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/bilder/logo/logo_vsg.jpg</url>
<link>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de</link>
</image>

<item>
<title>Faszination AMIGA</title>
<description>von Stephan Ricken, 05/2014 <![CDATA[<p><img src="http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/bilder/vorschaubilder/amiga.jpg" width="400" height="250"/><br />]]></description>
<comments>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/amiga.html#vionlink_comments</comments>
<link>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/amiga.html</link>
<guid>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/amiga.html</guid>
</item>

<item>
<title>Dracula-Logik</title>
<description>von Yoda Zhang, 04/2014 <![CDATA[<p><img src="http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/bilder/vorschaubilder/draculalogik.jpg" width="400" height="250"/><br />]]></description>
<comments>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/draculalogik.html#vionlink_comments</comments>
<link>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/draculalogik.html</link>
<guid>http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/draculalogik.html</guid>
</item>

...

</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting *all* the content of your `<description>` elements in `CDATA`. And make sure that the HTML in your `CDATA` is clean. You're not closing the `<p>` tag.

For example, replace:

`<description>von Stephan Ricken, 05/2014 <![CDATA[<p><img src="http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/bilder/vorschaubilder/amiga.jpg" width="400" height="250"/><br />]]></description>`

with

`<description><![CDATA[
  <p>von Stephan Ricken, 05/2014 <img src="http://www.videospielgeschichten.de/bilder/vorschaubilder/amiga.jpg" width="400" height="250"/></p>
]]></description>`

Comment: Many thanks for the hint. I changed the code to what you suggested. Seems as good as before. But still no images in "feedly" (OS X nor IOS). Still in bug in there?

Comment: Feedly is very likely caching your feed's content... which means you'll have to add new items in there to see if they are able to display them. You can't just look at past items :)

Comment: Ok, that is new to me. Thanks again. I always though the "feedly" feed would be refreshed on every change (which makes sense to me) and not only within new items. Will see then what happens.